# How to update multipe UILabel in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need some help for my problem. I've seen a lot of similar posts, and tried solutions, but none of them have worked for me.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in which I have multiple `UILabel` and a `UIButton` control. This control is suppose to update one of the labels from its cell. However, instead of updating the correct `UILabel` it updates the `UILabel` in the last cell.

My code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)inTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSInteger ETag = 111;
  static NSInteger STag = 112;

  .... // code

  if (cell == nil) {

  .... // code

   frame.origin.x = 85;
    frame.origin.y = 10;
    frame.size.height = 50;
    frame.size.width = 100;

    SLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    SLabel.tag = STag;
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:SLabel];
    //[SLabel release];

    frame.origin.x = 215;
    frame.origin.y = 10;
    frame.size.height = 50;
    frame.size.width = 100;

    ELabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    ELabel.tag = ETag;
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:ELabel];
    //[ELabel release];

   .... // code

   }

   .... // code

    ELabel = (UILabel *) [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:ETag];
    SLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:STag];

    ELabel.text = [s._episode stringValue];
    ELabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    ELabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ELabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    ELabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    ELabel.tag = 1000+indexPath.row;

    SLabel.text = [s._season stringValue];
    SLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    SLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    SLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    SLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    SLabel.tag = 1000+indexPath.row;
    ..... // code

    return cell;
    }
```

Thanks for reading and helping me.

Tommy

Thank you ! i resolved my problem with :

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];            
 UILabel *a = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:(1000+indexPath.row)]; 
 a.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"something"];
```

the issue was that tags were not unique

Comment: Do you mean that you have a control in each `UITableViewCell` and you would like for it to let you increase/decrease a number in that particular cell (which is in a `UILabel`) and right now is updating the `UILabel` in your last cell?

Comment: yes ! i tried something like             UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
            SLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
            SLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"something"]; but it doesn't work

Comment: View my answer, i completely described the approach that you should implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access needful `UILabel` via its `tag`, if it is unique in your view.
For example, you have `UITableView` with multiple cells. Each cell contains `UILabel` that might be updated. Let's set unique tags for that labels, let them be your `indexPath.row` of `UITableViewCell` (it is already done in your code).

Then when you want to update some cell with `tag == cellsTagToUpdate` you should just get reference to that cell via call to `UITableView *tableView`: `UILabel *labelToUpdate = [tableView viewWithTag:cellsTagToUpdate]`.

Now you have reference to your label that you want to update. Before updating you should check if `cell` is not nil. It would be nil if that view (`UILabel`) is not now visible and was removed from `superview`.

Comment: Thank you ! i resolved my problem with             UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UILabel *a = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:(1000+indexPath.row)];
            NSLog(@"slabel.Tag : %i", a.tag);
            a.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"something"]; the issue was that tags were not unique

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you always can get a reference to you cells with `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` and then get the UILabel within the cell with viewWithTag and set the text of the label you want.

Comment: ok something like :             UILabel *someLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
            someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", @"something"];

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:STag]; label.text = @"Something here";

Comment: It is bad decision because when you will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will always rerun all your code in that method, but it is unnedful as you have already set all parameters and create all subviews. View my answer and try to implement it with unique tags. It will be more optimally to your table.

Comment: I edited something ... First you get the UILabel with the label tag's that you set on the cellForRowAtIndexPath: (SLabel.tag = STag;), not with the indexPath.row; and you can't use the %i (used for int's) mark to print a NSString, instead use %@ ...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do is get the `indexPath` from `UITableViewDelegate` `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` selector and store it in some way (a property would suffice).

Then in your button selector could call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` For the cell corresponding to `indexPath` selected in order to update the text of any of its `UILabel` 's and now:

```
ELabel = (UILabel *) [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:ETag];
SLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:STag];
```

Comment: It is bad decision because when you will call cellForRowAtIndexPath it will always rerun all your code in that method, but it is unnedful as you have already set all parameters and create all subviews. It will be more optimally to your table.

Comment: It's just a selector call, when you send reloadData message to tableView is when all the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate selectors call too... If you check the UITableView class reference you can see a cellForRowAtIndexPath: selector

Comment: If you could read the method, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns a UITableViewCell which you can catch and use however you want

Answer (score -2):

Edit: See Nektos answer

Nevertheless his way to layout and set the data is not how you should do this. He could do layout via IB and apply the standard pattern: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: You are wrong. He has global variables `SLabel` and `ELabel`, so it is not problem when he initialise labels for cells. Moreover if he will do as you suggest then he will create unneedful labels when reusing the previously created cell. So his code is right.